# Is any chess software specifically for forced mates?

Tags: software, checkmate

Is any chess software specifically for forced mates?

In particular, such software can only prune the search tree when it can *prove*

that the the move doesn't affect the existence of length of a forced mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Chest UCI](http://fhub.jimdo.com/), which is Franz Huber's UCI-adapter for Heiner Marxen's problem solver [Chest](http://www.drb.insel.de/~heiner/Chess/chest.html), is the obvious bet.

Answer (score 0):

Joseph Ellis on talkchess has a modified Stockfish for mate solving.

```
Updates: 

1) Sync with latest SF. 
2) Move to full hash key. 
3) Increase max depth to 250. 
4) Improve mate detection. 

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1145468/MateFinder.7z 

The archive includes the source and two very basic windows compiles.
```

http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=58597&highlight=mate+solver

The Github URL: https://github.com/jhellis3/Stockfish/tree/mate_finder

I never downloaded the archive and have no idea how good it is. I think it might worth a try as Joseph seemed to know what he was doing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some specialised programs for solving all kinds of chess problems (like Chloe or Alybadix). They can also treat a Chess position as a problem and look for mates in there.

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_for_handling_chess_problems